# Sqoop won't run on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, hadoop, jdbc, sqoop

I'm new to hadoop and trying to get sqoop working on my mac OS X.
I have installed hadoop and sqoop using brew. Version of hadoop is 3.1.2

Location at which sqoop got installed is: `/usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.6_1/`

sqoop-env.sh file looks like below:

```
export HADOOP_HOME="/usr/local/opt/hadoop"
export HBASE_HOME="/usr/local"
export HIVE_HOME="/usr/local"
export HCAT_HOME="/usr/local"
export ZOOCFGDIR="/usr/local/etc/zookeeper"
export ZOOKEEPER_HOME="/usr/local/opt/zookeeper"
```

I have check all the locations, they are correct. Below is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/ | grep hadoop`

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 adityad  admin   45 Apr 16 18:17 container-executor -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/bin/container-executor
lrwxr-xr-x  1 adityad  admin   33 Apr 16 18:17 hadoop -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/bin/hadoop
lrwxr-xr-x  1 adityad  admin   31 Apr 16 18:17 hdfs -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/bin/hdfs
lrwxr-xr-x  1 adityad  admin   33 Apr 16 18:17 mapred -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/bin/mapred
lrwxr-xr-x  1 adityad  admin   50 Apr 16 18:17 test-container-executor -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/bin/test-container-executor
lrwxr-xr-x  1 adityad  admin   31 Apr 16 18:17 yarn -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/bin/yarn
```

When I try to run any `sqoop` command, nothing happens. 
I tried running :

```
sqoop-list-tables --connect jdbc:postgresql://<host>:5432/<DB> --username <user> --password <password>
```

I just get below warnings:

```
Warning: /usr/local/lib/sqoop/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /usr/local/lib/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/local/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /usr/local/lib/sqoop/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
```

Even `sqoop-version` command gives nothing but the above warnings.

Comment: Did you run `sqoop-env.sh`?

Comment: @RichardBarber Yes I did.